# How to keep zeroes to the left of a number when opening a txt file with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I open a .txt with Excel, copy it to my .xls file, and run some VBA functions.

When there are zeroes to the left of a number, Excel deletes them and the program fails because the number is in fact a string.

How can I copy them with the zeroes?

When I open the .txt with Excel, it opens without the zeroes, so I cannot format anything at that point.

The .txt is dynamic, as the number of characters of the numbers.
A random example of the .txt content:
`H  00013   SUPB4   00551   LEM 2252.554    00548   00540   00`

The main code is:

```
    Workbooks.OpenText ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Text.txt", Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)

    UltLinea = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:Z" & UltLinea).Copy

    Hoja1Text = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(Hoja1GenDocs).Activate
    Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Workbooks(Hoja1Text).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
    Range("A1").Select
```

I tried modifying the "normal" Style, changing the number to @ (text), but when a new file is opened, Excel loses this configuration.

Comment: the number proceeded by an = and wrapped in quotes works not sure how this works with your current flow though  i.e. ="00001230" you should also format the column in the new workbook to be text i.e. `.NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: In your `FieldInfo` parameter change the second number to 2, this should treat the data as text.  Different numbers correspond to different types of data.  Note this is only effecting your first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `.OpenText` to open the text file. Use the `.QueryTable` to import the file. For example if you text file looks like this

```
H 00013 SUPB4 00551 LEM 2252.554 00548 00540 00
```

Then us this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fName As String

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Text.txt"

    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & fName, Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "tempfile"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```